# Why PIVOT in Sql server output one row only?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

Tabl: Occupation (Name, Profession)

```
Name    Profession
Zahid   Engineer
Rakib   Doctor
David   Singer
Farid   Player
Arif    Doctor
Tarik   Singer
```

Expected Output:

```
Doctor Engineer Singer Player
Rakib  Zahid    David  Farid
Arif   NULL     Tarik  NULL
```

I tried:

```
Select Doctor, Engineer, Singer, Player 
from 
( Select [Name], Profession from Occupation ) T1
PIVOT
(Max([Name]) for Profession IN ( Doctor, Engineer, Singer, Player)) T2
```

But, It output only 1 row:

```
Doctor  Engineer    Singer  Player
Rakib   Zahid   Tarik   Farid
```

Comment: Is there another column which indicates sequence or groupings ?

Comment: When you aren't grouping by anything, then aggregation does only return 1 row.

Comment: You've said you want the `MAX(Name)` for each `Profession`. Why would you expect that to produce more than one result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With no GTD of order

```
Select *
 From  (
        Select [Name]
              ,[Profession]
              ,RN = row_number() over (partition by Profession order by Profession) 
         from Occupation 
       ) src
 Pivot (Max([Name]) for Profession IN ( Doctor, Engineer, Singer, Player)) pvt
```

**Results**

```
RN  Doctor  Engineer    Singer  Player
1   Rakib   Zahid       David   Farid
2   Arif    NULL        Tarik   NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps what you need is an arbitrary `ROW_NUMBER` value in your derived table:

```sql
WITH Occupation AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM(VALUES('Zahid','Engineer'),
               ('Rakib','Doctor'),
               ('David','Singer'),
               ('Farid','Player'),
               ('Arif ','Doctor'),
               ('Tarik','Singer'))V([Name],Profession))
SELECT --P.RN,
       P.Doctor,
       P.Engineer,
       P.Singer,
       P.Player 
FROM (SELECT [Name],
             Profession,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Profession ORDER BY [Name]) AS RN
      FROM Occupation) O
PIVOT
(Max([Name]) for Profession IN ( Doctor, Engineer, Singer, Player)) P;
```